# Docker can't find package.json

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I recently started running postgres from a docker container and migrated my backend to a separate container. Here's my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
   postgres:
      image: postgres:9.6-alpine
      ports:
         - "5432"
      volumes:
         - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

   backend:
      build:
         context: ./
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
          - ../../:/var/www
      ports:
          - "3000:3000"
      links:
          - postgres
      restart: always
      environment:
         - PORT=3000
         - HOST=0.0.0.0
         - PG_HOST=postgres
         - PG_USER=postgres
         - PG_DATABASE=postgres
         - NODE_ENV=development

  volumes:
      postgres_data:
```

And here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk add -U python g++ yarn nodejs npm make 
WORKDIR /var/www/server

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN pwd
RUN ls -l

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And my Makefile looks like this

```
build: docker-compose.yml
   docker-compose build
   touch build

dev: build
   docker-compose up
```

And my project structure looks like this

```
server
├── app
│   ├── db
│   └── models
├── build
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── index.js
├── Makefile
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── README.md
```

So I run `make dev` to create the docker container and when I actually bring the docker container up, I keep getting the error

```
npm ERR! path /var/www/server/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/server/package.json'
```

However, the output of my ls -l in the project directory in the docker container is

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           205 Apr  4 16:39 Dockerfile
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            96 Apr  4 06:19 Makefile
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           216 Apr  4 04:10 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Apr  4 16:36 app
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Apr  4 16:38 build
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           561 Apr  4 16:39 docker-compose.yml
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           205 Apr  4 16:36 index.js
drwxrwxrwx  176 root     root          4096 Apr  4 04:32 node_modules
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root         24143 Apr  4 04:28 package-lock.json
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           676 Apr  4 16:36 package.json
```

and package.json is there. I've also tried setting CMD to just node index.js in the Dockerfile but that didn't work either, saying that index.js couldn't be found, which leads me to believe that I might not be in the right directory (?).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by mounting this volume `- ../../:/var/www` in your docker-compose?

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem is that by mounting the directory you are overwriting everything you did in your build steps. If you don't have a reason for mounting that volume, try removing it and I think it should work.

Comment: Ah that was the problem...thanks for explaining the reason!